# Сплайн-аппроксимация

Tags: c++

Нет ли у кого-нибудь ссылки на Си-шную программу для расчета аппроксимирующего кубического сплайна? Очень бы хотелось.

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите [здесь](http://astronomy.nmsu.edu/cwc/Teaching/ASTR545/HW/splinecodes.c) на функции spline и splint, это код по книге Numerical Recipies in C (Cubic Spline Interpolation).

Также может пригодиться:

- [Spline interpolation](http://www.alglib.net/interpolation/spline3.php)
- [The SINTEF Spline Library](http://www.sintef.no/Informasjons--og-kommunikasjonsteknologi-IKT/Anvendt-matematikk/Fagomrader/Geometri/Prosjekter/The-SISL-Nurbs-Library/SISL-Homepage/)